# php delete mysql row from id 9809 to id 17275

Tags: php, mysql

how to delete mysql row from id 9809 to id 17275?

```
sql =" DELETE from Table WHERE id = 9809 to id= 17275"
```

how to delete from  the start id to the end id?

Comment: [`BETWEEN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between)

Answer (score 3):

if you want delete a range of numeric values you could use  between

```
  sql =" DELETE from Table WHERE id between  9809 and  17275"
```

Answer (score 1):

it must be

```
$sql = " DELETE from Table WHERE id between 9809 and 17275"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE from Table WHERE cast(id as unsigned) >= 9809 and  cast(id as unsigned)<=17275;
```

Comment: Any explanation on why you're not using BETWEEN (like the existing answers) and why you're casting the id's?